# How do I switch from visual mode directly to insert mode?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I am in visual mode, then I change my mind and want to switch to insert mode. Is there a key to switch directly, or do I have to do ESC-i and go through normal mode?

Comment: There's no direct way. You could create a key binding to do it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected

Comment: Oh wait - it isn't actually true, see accepted answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go directly to insert mode from visual mode by pressing

```
  shift i  (uppercase i)
```

Let me know if that isn't what you need.

Comment: Great, I've been looking for this for aaaages!! Thanks